# OPENGL GLUT compiler can't find functions

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-construction, glut

Im pretty new to opengl, and im getting errors saying that it can't find the functions: glColor3f, glVertex2f, and also pRect. My includes are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef MAC
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

and the code in question is:

```
void display()
{
    // Rotate objects
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);   //We want to draw a quad, i.e. shape with four sides
    glColor3F(1, 0, 0); //Set the colour to red
    glVertex2F(0, 0);            //Draw the four corners of the rectangle
    glVertex2F(0, pRect->h);
    glVertex2F(pRect->w, pRect->h);
    glVertex2F(pRect->w, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //glFlush();
}
```

I think i'm including all the necessary files, and when I compile it I use the command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lgut -IGL -IGLU
```

But that doesn't seem to be the problem either. Any advice would be wonderful! Thanks a million!

EDIT:
changed

```
 g++ main.cpp -lgut -IGL -IGLU
```

to

```
g++ main.cpp -lgut -lGL -lGLU
```

the error code was:

```
 glColor3F : not declared in this scope
 glVertex2F : not declared in this scope
 pRect: not declared in this scope
```

Comment: its glColor3f -- note 'f' is not capatilized

Comment: You would need to post something about what the problem is, what the error is, what you have tried, etc, for this to be a valid question

Comment: I don't use GCC, but this: `-lgut -IGL -IGLU` seems wrong to me. As I understood it, the way libraries are included on the command line is with `-l` (not `-I`) followed by the library name. And `gut` is not the same as `glut`.

Comment: @user814628: That was the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I figured that part out after I posted the question. sometimes I have a hard time seeing the differences on those two characters.